# How to autoplay an audio stream at startup?

Tags: pi-3, audio, radio

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi create an internet radio player that only needs to play one station, but always plays that station on startup. I know I need mpd and mpc and to enter the URL of the stream, but how do I make that particular stream always play on startup?

Answer (score 1):

you'd want to edit the start up script below

`/etc/rc.local`

and launch the program.

see [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) for more details.

Comment: that's really only a link-only answer. You do have to be a bit careful with rc.local, as it's running with elevated privileges and you have to ensure that your task forks to allow other startup items to run

Answer (score 0):

You can put your command to run the app in autostart for the lxsession manager. For example, I use the following to setup the autostart script putting with my command :

echo "@lxterminal -e 'audioInjector.RCA.thruTest.sh'" >> ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

The "@lxterminal" fires up an lxterminal to execute a bash script once the window manager starts.

You can change that to whatever you want to start by first logging into the Pi or getting up a terminal there and :

echo "yourCommand" >> ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

This will add "yourCommand" to the autostart script.

Comment: This will work as long as the user Pi has autologin enabled. Otherwise this won't work at boot until Pi logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that runs as a regular user and doesn't rely on LXDE is **cron**. Anything in a `@reboot` clause will be run as soon as possible after boot. To edit your cron jobs, enter `crontab -e`.

An example entry I recently set up for an art exhibition plays an mp3 as a continuous loop:

```
@reboot    sleep 29; nohup mpg321 -l 0 /home/pi/Music/background.mp3 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Though it's not a stream player, it should help give you an idea of another way of doing it. The command breaks down as:

- `sleep 29` - a not-very-scientific way of waiting until other jobs have started. [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59981/raspbian-jessie-wait-for-network-vs-cron-reboot-entries/59984#59984) answer might help if you need to understand when various jobs start relative to cron.
- `nohup … 2>&1 > /dev/null` - a wrapper to fully detach and silence any console output from the task I want to run. All output and error messages disappear.
- `mpg321 -l 0 /home/pi/Music/background.mp3` - the player task itself. As with all cron jobs, you need to specify full paths for any data and non-system commands. (As an aside for anyone trying to loop an mp3: you may need to make some [special preparations](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/how-to-make-compressed-audio-loop-without-audible-gap/19026#19026), and iTunes uses its own loop/gapless tags that are generally incompatible with Linux players.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a watchdog script that runs in crontab every minute. This will also restart the stream if for some reason it crashed.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> if [ -z $(ps aux | grep "[the command that runs your stream]" | grep -v grep) ]; then    
>  [the command that runs your stream] & 
>  else exit
> fi
>
> exit
> ```