# Raspbian Jessie "wait for network" Vs. Cron @reboot entries

Tags: raspbian, networking, boot, raspi-config, cron

I have a few Raspbian cron entries that runs @reboot. Some are network dependent (i.e. ntp-wait).

My question is, with Raspbian Jessie, if "wait for network" is enabled in raspi-config, will cron run these entries before the network is up or will the entire system halt until the network is up? In other words, where in the boot-up sequence is crontab activated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will the entire system halt until the network is up

No.

> where in the boot-up sequence is crontab activated?

Crontabs are managed by [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), a system daemon started by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which on Raspbian jessie is **systemd**.

Exactly when a service is started in terms of time depends on what it depends on, and a degree of indeterminacy, since things that do not depend on one another may be started in parallel.  You can get a fancy graph of everything from the last boot with `systemd-analyze plot > sysd.svg` --- unfortunately, the plain jane text output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` won't include `cron.service` because it isn't part of the "critical chain".  However, .svg files are viewable in a web browser (and you should be able to text search them there as well).  Here's an example from a headless Pi running Jessie, with `cron` enabled -- you'll have to "open image in a new tab" to make this legible, and S.E. does not allow .svg uploads, so I converted it to a .png, which are not text searchable.

[image]

You can find `cron` down near the bottom, starting at around the 18s mark (this is on a B+).  My networking is done in an oddball manner, but I think on a more stock system this will probably be *after* an ethernet connection is already established, or within a few seconds of wifi (which can take a more variable amount of time).

You can get a dependency tree, which is simpler and more abstract, with `systemctl list-dependencies --after cron`.  It might look like this, with the dots either red or green to indicate the state of the service:

```
cron.service
● ├─system.slice
● ├─systemd-journald.socket
● └─basic.target
●   ├─systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
●   ├─paths.target
●   │ ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
●   │ └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path
●   ├─slices.target
●   │ ├─-.slice
●   │ ├─system.slice
●   │ └─user.slice
●   ├─sockets.target
●   │ ├─avahi-daemon.socket
●   │ ├─dbus.socket
●   │ ├─syslog.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-initctl.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-journald.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-shutdownd.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-udevd-control.socket
●   │ └─systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
●   ├─sysinit.target
●   │ ├─console-setup.service
●   │ ├─debian-fixup.service
●   │ ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   │ ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   │ ├─emergency.service
●   │ ├─fake-hwclock.service
●   │ ├─hdparm.service
●   │ ├─kbd.service
●   │ ├─keyboard-setup.service
●   │ ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   │ ├─networking.service
●   │ ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   │ ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   │ ├─raspi-config.service
●   │ ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   │ ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   │ ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   │ ├─systemd-binfmt.service
●   │ ├─systemd-journald.service
●   │ ├─systemd-modules-load.service
●   │ ├─systemd-random-seed.service
●   │ ├─systemd-readahead-collect.service
●   │ ├─systemd-readahead-replay.service
●   │ ├─systemd-sysctl.service
●   │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   │ ├─systemd-udev-settle.service
●   │ ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   │ ├─systemd-udevd.service
●   │ ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   │ ├─cryptsetup.target
●   │ ├─emergency.target
●   │ │ └─emergency.service
●   │ ├─local-fs.target
●   │ │ ├─-.mount
●   │ │ ├─boot-BOOT.mount
●   │ │ ├─boot.mount
●   │ │ ├─mnt-hd.mount
●   │ │ ├─mnt-hd2-raspberry_pi-boot.mount
●   │ │ ├─mnt-hd2-raspberry_pi-root.mount
●   │ │ ├─mnt-hd2.mount
●   │ │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   │ │ └─local-fs-pre.target
●   │ │   ├─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   │ │   └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   │ └─swap.target
●   └─timers.target
●     └─systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
```

The `--after` means this is stuff that cron depends on (and the stuff that stuff depends on), i.e., it is stuff cron starts *after*.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Out of curiosity, at what process is the network activated (or halted for)?

Comment: In general "networking" would be the root of it; you may also want to check and see if `NetworkManager` is in play on your system (it isn't above, and note these aren't direct dependencies for cron) -- `systemctl list-units | grep -i network` will show you a list of likely candidates.  When something like that *starts* is not necessarily indicative of when an actual connection to an external network has been established, but again, with ethernet I think within a few seconds, with wifi it may be 5-10.